# abstract classes without abstract methods creating objects in python

Tags: python, abstract-class

Basically, I knew that abstract base classes are used as skeleton classes just like regular classes, but enforces that abstract methods should be overridden by the child/inherited classes if it has one like below

```
Class AbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def absmethod(self):
        pass

class ChildClass(AbstractClass):
    def absmethod(self):
        print "Yeah!"

obj = ChildClass()
```

So we can create an object of `ChildClass` as above

We know we can't instantiate an abstract class as it meant to be just skeleton and we will get an error if we try to instantiate it as below

```
obj = AbstractClass()

*** TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class AbstractClass with abstract methods absmethod
```

But what my actual query about posting this `StackOverflow` is if we create an abstract class by using `abc.ABCMeta`, without abstract methods, I can able to create an instance of the abstract class which should not be the case(correct me if I am wrong)

```
Class AbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

obj = AbstractClass()
```

**OOOPPPSS** it worked, we can actually create an object of abstract classes without abstract methods? So please let me know the key points behind this

Comment: There is little gain in having an abstract class without any abstract methods in Python. I myself thought I'd need it but then noticed that the only place I'd actually refer to that class was in type annotations. Instead I used the following: `AbstractClass = Union[ChildClass, ...]`.

Answer (score 11):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> A class that has a metaclass derived from `ABCMeta` cannot be
>   instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are
>   overridden.

Conversely, this means that any class with no abstract methods or properties like your `AbstractClass` *can* be instantiated.

---

If you want to disallow instantiation of the topmost parent class, you can write a custom class that performs a type check in its [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method:

```
class SubclassOnlyABC(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.__bases__ == (SubclassOnlyABC,):
            msg = 'Abstract class {} cannot be instantiated'.format(cls.__name__)
            raise TypeError(msg)

        return super(SubclassOnlyABC, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
class AbstractClass(SubclassOnlyABC):
    pass

class ChildClass(AbstractClass):
    pass

ChildClass()  # works because it's a child class of an abstract class
AbstractClass()  # throws TypeError because its parent class is "object"
```

---

You can also write a `__new__` method that prevents instantiation of classes with no abstract methods:

```
class NonEmptyABC(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if ANY abstractmethod exists
        for parentcls in cls.__mro__:
            if any(getattr(attr, '__isabstractmethod__', False)
                               for attr in vars(parentcls).values()):
                break
        else:
            msg = 'Abstract class {} cannot be instantiated'.format(cls.__name__)
            raise TypeError(msg)

        return super(NonEmptyABC, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
class EmptyAbstractClass(NonEmptyABC):
    pass

class NonemptyAbstractClass(NonEmptyABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class NonemptyChild(NonemptyAbstractClass):
    def foo(self):
        pass

NonemptyChild()  # works because "foo" is an abstractmethod
EmptyAbstractClass()  # throws TypeError because there are no abstractmethods
```

Comment: I really like this implementation but I don't believe `inspect.isabstract(NonEmptyABC)` returns `True`

Answer (score 7):

Since Python is a dynamic languages, the very idea of enforcing classes to inherit from a particular class goes against duck typing. Hence, the use case of Abstract classes in Python is pretty limited and provided more for a conventional reason. Still if you want to block the instantiation of a class without declaring virtual methods, you can,  however,

```
class AbstractClass(object):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is AbstractClass:
            raise Exception('Abstract class cannot be instantiatied')

        return object.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually just declare the base class's `__init__` with `@abc.abstractmethod`.
If my base class does not have an `__init__`, I add a trivial one.

Something like this:

```
class AbstractClass(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # other useful non-abstract methods...


class ChildClass(AbstractClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    child = ChildClass()  # allowed
    abstract = AbstractClass()  # TypeError
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution without using ABC. More on specific case it required for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316282/python-hierarchy-of-abstract-classes-without-abstract-methods)

```py
class AbstractClass:
    _is_abstract = True

    def __init__(self):
        if self._is_abstract:
            raise RuntimeError("Abstract class instantiation.")
        # do initialization

    def __init_subclass__(self):   # is called every time class is subclassed
        self._is_abstract = False  # thus makes sure abstract check returns False on subclass
```

Comment: The OP is not asking how can his example work properly, he is asking why should it be possible for the example to work