# Python: hierarchy of abstract classes without abstract methods

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class

So, here is a problem:

1. I want to define an abstract class, let's say `AbstractA`, which does not require subclasses to implement any of its methods, but rather to extend its functionality. In terms of Java that would be interface class.
2. Moreover, I want to be able to create an abstract subclass, let's say `AbstractB`, of the `AbstractA` with the same properties, but some methods redefining or extending base class methods.

I don't want though to make class (`AbstractA`) abstract e.g. [through the check of class name in `__init__` or `__new__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099600/abstract-classes-without-abstract-methods-creating-objects-in-python), because that would require abstract subclass (`AbstractB`) to redefine that method along with it's main functionality, i.e. construction or initialization of a new instance. Or to call `super().__init__(...)` which I'd prefer to avoid as well (maybe I'm wrong here).

So, I want something like that:

```py
class AbstractA:
    def __init__(self):
        # do initialization stuff

    def very_common_method(self, ...):
        # do very common stuff

class AbstractB(AbstractA):
    # do not duplicate initialization stuff here, inherit instead

    def less_common_method(self, ...):
        # do less common stuff

class AX(AbstractA):
    def specific_method_1(self, ...):

class BX(AbstractB):
    def specific_method_2(self, ...):

# Instantiating AbstractA or AbstractB should result in error.
# Instantiating AX or BX should not.
```

Below I have a possible solution.
Is there any disadvantages I overlook? Better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Should `class AX(AbstractA): pass` be legal? What would be the point of disallowing direct instantiation of `AbstractA` but allowing instantiation of `AX`?

Comment: @chepner, fair question. I must accept this requirement is more of a preference than necessity.
The reason I want to have abstract class is because instantiating this parent class semantically makes no sense. Like if in implementing virtual animals it doesn't make sense to instantiate animal or mammal. Instead one should instantiate more detailed species. So I want to make it harder to misuse the class solely purposed to define common properties.
As for the fist part, it isn't hard enough to completely prohibit mususe, but enough to prevent it by accident. Kinda like _private_identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's possible solution:

```py
class AbstractA:
    _is_abstract = True

    def __init__(self):
        if self._is_abstract:
            raise RuntimeError("Abstract class instantiation.")
        # do initialization stuff

    def __init_subclass__(self):   # is called every time class is subclassed
        self._is_abstract = False  # thus makes sure abstract check fails on a subclass

class AbstractMixin:
    def __init_subclass__(self):
        self._is_abstract = True

class AbstractB(AbstractMixin, AbstractA):  # AbstractMixin takes precendence on MRO,
    # inherit __init__                      # so the class abstract check returns True.

    def __init_subclass__(self):
        self._is_abstract = False

class A(AbstractA):
    pass

class B(AbstractB):
    pass

AbstractA()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
RuntimeError: Abstract class instantiation.

AbstractB()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
RuntimeError: Abstract class instantiation.

A()
<__main__.A object at 0x7f0bba5112e8>

B()
<__main__.B object at 0x7f0bba511438>
```

Comment: Why does `AbstractB` include a `def __init_subclass__(self): self._is_abstract = False` method? Is that necessitated by its inheriting from `AbstractA`, even though the method has no `@abc.abstractmethod` decorator?

Comment: @J.G. it is necessitated by inheriting from `AbstractMixin` as a first parent. We want `AbstractMixin.__init_subclass__()` to take precedence when `AbstractB` is instantiated, but not let it to be inherited and thus make any subclass of `AbstractB` abstract as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__ == A:
            raise RuntimeError("Abstract class instantiation.")
        print(self.__class__.__name__)


class B(A):
    pass
```

```
>>> A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
RuntimeError: Abstract class instantiation.
```

```
>>> B()
B
<__main__.B object at 0x7f8c816a58d0>
>>>
```

Comment: I have specifically mentioned this approach and why I don't want to use it in a question.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you would probably implement the "abstract" base classes as mix-ins. There's nothing special you need to do; by convention, you would add `Mixin` to the name to indicate that it isn't meant to be instantiated directly, but simply used as a base class for other classes.

```
class AMixin:
    def __init__(self):
        # do initialization stuff

    def very_common_method(self, ...):
        # do very common stuff

class BMixin(AMixin):
    # do not duplicate initialization stuff here, inherit instead

    def less_common_method(self, ...):
        # do less common stuff

class AX(AMixin):
    def specific_method_1(self, ...):

class BX(BMixin):
    def specific_method_2(self, ...):

class Foo:
    ...

class Bar(Foo, BMixin):
    ...
```

Comment: `Mixin` in the name doesn't indicate it just should be "used as a base class", it rather indicates, it should be used as a mixin, i.e. secondary, tertiary, etc parent, providing some additional piece of functionality.